# Synchronize Custom post type tags to WordPress default posts tags

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I am new with WordPress plugin development. I have to Synchronize custom post type tags with WordPress default post type tags.
So when user will create, delete or update any custom post type tag it should be updated in Default tags.
I do not have enough knowledge with WordPress hooks so if someone guide me about this that will be appreciated.
This is urgent task for me to do so i have to find out the solution for this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the [`post_tag` taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) for the post type.

For a quick, after the fact, way to do this (meaning the CPT has already been registered, etc.), you can use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).

A workable example is below. Edit the value for `$object_type`, and place the example below in the *functions.php* of your child theme:

```
  add_action( 'init', 'my_cpt_has_tags_now' );
  function my_cpt_has_tags_now() {
       $taxonomy    = "post_tag";
       $object_type = "name_of_your_cpt";

       register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $object_type );
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But i am asking some thing different. I have already tags for my my custom post type but now i have to synchronize custom post types taxonomy (tags) with WordPress default Posts tags. So now if i will create update or delete custom post type tags then these should be updated in default posts tags. If you will guide me about this i will really appreciate it because it is important and urgent task me.
Thank you!!

Comment: ok, so you have a cpt taxonomy named `tags` and you want it to be _synchronized_ with the wp taxonomy `post_tag`. Can you explain what you mean by synchronized? If they are the same terms in both, why not have them use one _shared_ taxonomy? In any event there is a do_action() hook used by wp_insert_term() you may be able to use to do what you want. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but i have two separate taxonomies. I could not share one taxonomy because both these are have different uses. This is my client requirement and he want that when he will create any tag for custom post type it should automatically added in default wp tags. Same should happens on update and on delete.

Comment: ah, ok. perhaps doing an `add_action` hooked to `create_{$taxonomy}` with a callback function that uses `wp_insert_term()` to add the term being created to the `post_tag` tax after you've checked it's a relevant scenario. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/

Comment: several other update/delete hooks listed here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/taxonomy.php/

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. i will implement this and i hope it will work.